# How to bind a multiple of a certain function to a key in evil-mode? (Ex. 5 lines down = `5j`)

Tags: evil, vim-emulation

In vim, if i want to move 5 lines down i press `J` given that my `xnoremap J 5j`.

How do i reproduce this in emacs evil mode? The clue i have is that `(define-key evil-normal-state-map "j" 'evil-next-visual-line)` gets me onto the next line. How to "multiple" `evil-next-visual-line` symbol times 5?

Comment: I know no evil but doesn't `C-u 5 j` work? If it does, you can supply any multiplier you want.

Comment: @NickD Actually, in `evil-normal-state-map`, `5` maps to `C-u 5`. So `5j` would be `C-u 5 j` like you said. And it works just fine. But I believe OP wants sth like `xnoremap J 5j`. It's a common cfg for people from vim background to set. :-)

Comment: @TerryTsao what do you mean by a `cfg`? Context-free grammar?)

Comment: @rtviii configuration. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc:

> (evil-next-visual-line &optional COUNT)
>
> Move the cursor COUNT screen lines down.

Since lots of evil commands take an optional count (usually provided with digit-argument), you can write one easily like this:

```lisp
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "J")
  (lambda nil (interactive) (evil-next-visual-line 5)))
```

Comment: how would i replicate this for visual/selection mode in emacs? Basically i want consistency of being able to jump 5 both when im moving around in `normal` and selecting a chunk in `visual`. Read about something called evil-motion-state-map, but just replicating the above with motion instead of normal didnt work.

Comment: @rtviii Please try setting `evil-motion-state-map` for that.